# Order values in select option list - php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, html-select

I am new to coding and have the below select option list that is returning unordered values. The code checks the database for existing values (number of bedrooms) and returns them as options in the list. I would like to order them in an ascending manner:

```
<select class="bedrooms" name="Bedrooms" id="Bedrooms" >
    <option value="">BEDROOMS</option>
      <?php if ($bed_room): ?>          
        <?php foreach ($bed_room as $key => $value): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $value['bed_room'] ?>"><?php echo $value['bed_room'] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php endif ?>
</select>
```

Comment: You can do that in your query, post your query too

Comment: @Panda I've been through the page that the developer submitted and I cannot see the query on this page, is it possible that the query is defined on another page and it is being referenced here?

Comment: where is `$bed_room` defined? this should be the result of the query

Comment: Maybe you can do something with asort: http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php or even better: http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php (natural sorting) on your array. How ever, I would suggest to do this in your query to avoid messy code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to search for (`$bed_room`) in your files so you can see from where it is getting the values and from there you can sort it as you like

or you can sort the array itself like this:

```
natsort($bed_room);
```

```
<select class="bedrooms" name="Bedrooms" id="Bedrooms" >
<option value="">BEDROOMS</option>
  <?php if ($bed_room): ?> 
    <?php natsort($bed_room);>         
    <?php foreach ($bed_room as $key => $value): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value['bed_room'] ?>"><?php echo $value['bed_room'] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endif ?>
</select>
```

Comment: natsort() is a nice option. How ever I would really suggest him to edit his query. I would suggest this in your post. If he does all his sorting this way, it'll give a leak of speed. But as he can't find the query, this is probably the best way to do it.